# The IF function in Excel is not working?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

For example:

`D1=3, D2=5, D3=3.5`

I type the formula `D1<=D3<=D2` which is obviously true but excel keeps telling me its false and then proceeds to mess up all my other formulas.

But if I instead type `D2>=D3>=D1` (which is exactly the same formula), excel will tell me its true and give the correct value.

This would solve the problem, but if D3 were to equal 6.8 for example, excel still tells me this is true when it clearly isn't.

If I flip the formula again, excel will rightly tell me that it is indeed false. Unfortunatly now I cannot test different scenarios without retyping the formula every single time.

Answer (score 5):

Use this: `=AND(D1<=D3, D3<=D2)`.
Excel computes the formula using an order of precedence:  `D1 <= D2` evaluates to `TRUE`.  `TRUE <= D2` evaluates to `FALSE`.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your data is formatted incorrectly. Right click and goto format. Make sure this is either set to general or number. If it is already general then try changing it to number. If excel thinks a cell is text it won't do conditions like that correctly.